Event Sourcing selecting foreign key relationships in command handlers?
I am new to CQRS and Event Sourcing.
I have problems either properly modelling my Domain or I am misunderstanding something (highly likely).
Domain background. We have a collection of Lines. The lines have a direction and keep track of which Hole is to the left and right of it. So together the lines build up a "spiderweb".
// Model
public class Hole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }
    public int? HoleLeft { get; set; }
    public int? HoleRight { get; set; }

    // Extra code to store events, apply events and keep track of uncommitted events.
}

We also keep track of the Holes on the outside of the web. Therefor some lines only has either a HoleLeft or a HoleRight. Now to the problem. Say that we send new CreateLineCommand. We have business logic that demands that

A line has either a HoleLeft or a HoleRight
The HoleLeft/Right exists
No line crosses another line

In the command handler I can then do something like this.
public class CreateLineCommandHandler
{
    private readonly ILineRepository _lineRepo;
    private readonly IHoleRepository _holeRepo;

    public CreateLineCommandHandler(ILineRepository lineRepository, IHoleRepository holeRepository)
    {
        _lineRepo = lineRepository;
        _holeRepo = holeRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateLineCommand command)
    {
        Hole left = _holeRepo.GetById(command.HoleLeft);
        Hole right = _holeRepo.GetById(command.HoleRight);
        
        if (command.HoleLeft is null && command.HoleRight is null)
            throw new Exception("Only left or right can be null, not both.");

        if (command.HoleLeft == command.HoleRight)
            throw new Exception("Left and right holes can not be the same.");

        if (command.HoleLeft is not null && left is null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to find left hole");

        if (command.HoleRight is not null && right is null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to find right hole");

        // Now what I would like to do is something like this.
        List<Line> lines = _lineRepo.GetLinesFromHoles([left.id, right.id]);

        foreach (Line l in lines)
        {
            // check if crossing and if so throw exception.
        }

        Line line = new Line(command.Id,
                             command.Start,
                             command.End,
                             command.HoleLeft,
                             command.HoleRight);

        _lineRepo.Save(line);
    }
}

My repositories are the connection to the event store. So GetById fetches all events for the aggregate id input, applies all the events and returns the result. Save will get all uncommitted events and save those.
A GetLinesFromHoles command seems impossible unless I involve the read model. In a relational db this would be an easy select statement. Maybe this was too long a preamble to ask how can we do execute business logic in command handlers that requires data from other aggregates or via "foreign keys" when we are working with an event store.
I've tried the above solution and get stuck at this fundamental issue. I've looked around on stack overflow and googled the issue without success.


how can we do execute business logic in command handlers that requires data from other aggregates or via "foreign keys" when we are working with an event store.

Good news: the normal thing to do when your domain logic depends on information from "somewhere else" is to make a copy of the information you need (aka a "read model") and use that.
Under ideal conditions, you would load that read model at the same time as you load the information from your own data models, and then pass the lot to the domain logic.
Often conditions are less than ideal, and it may not be practical to "pre-fetch" a copy of the information you need, in which case the usual solution is to pass the capability to fetch a copy of the information you need.

Bad news: these solutions are really only painless in the cases where you don't need to worry about the external data changing while you are working with a stale copy (either because the external data doesn't ordinarily change, or because computing with a stale copy of the data produces acceptable results).
In cases where you need to be able to lock the external data to prevent changes while you are working on it, things get messy.
With a relational data model, you can sometimes arrange for your data transaction to lock the rows/tables of other "aggregates" so that you are certain to end up with a consistent data model.
But with event stores, generally, you are limited to locking only a single collection of events (the collection that you are writing to).
So you are either going to need to narrow your options of data stores to those that have the additional locking semantics you need, or to relax some of the constraints of your domain model, or to re-organize your data model such that all of the information you need to lock is in a single place.

Based on your description here, I would expect a review of your data model to be most useful.
If you've got constraints that require holes to be considered when manipulating lines, or vice versa, then perhaps the right design is that all of the events of the "spiderweb" belong together when processing the commands.
This is essentially the same sort of analysis we see in domain driven design, where we need to consider if the information associated with lines and the information associated with holes need to be part of the same "aggregate" (cluster of objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes).
